# PHP How much memory does a function that only call another function like call_func(){func()} takes?

Tags: php, function, memory-management

I have a function 

`function func(){ //somecode }` 

and
 `function call_func(){ func(); }`

so how much memory does call_function use?
and if I used many function like `call_func_1()` `call_func_2()` `call func_3()`
to call `func()` is it bad?

> I got this question because this

I am using codeigniter framework,
In codeigniter if I have a controller php file named location.. and in that location controller, there is a function named `index()`,

Inside `Index()` function I have a code that receive get parameter that is used for searching something and output it as page..

so if  i access `www.something.com/location?city="Indonesia"&location="jakarta"` 
It will display the search result...
I wanted to make the link pretty by calling `www.something.com/location/location_in_indonesia` and the parameter I use Post

So in codeigniter if i used `www.something.com/location/location_in_indonesia` I will be calling a function named location_in_indonesia from location.php because I dont want to copy the code that do the search, I just use 
`function location_in_indonesia(){
      $this->index()
      //which called the function index and display the search result

 }`

and if i have another country to search then i need to add many function
But later after I posted this,I think this can be resolved by using routes feature that is provided by codeigniter. I was wondering about if it is bad to use that function that is just calling another function. So I asked this question.

Comment: Is there any specific problem or is this more of a rhetorical question?

Comment: I added some information on my question about why I asked in this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a function from within another function this is what happens (note this is a generic description and not really PHP specific).

The calling function will push its current state into the *call stack* which as the name implies, is a stack (meaning the status will be placed on the top). The information that gets pushed is (roughly speaking) the position within the function at which the function call happened and references to variables in scope.

Now this implies that the memory taken in the stack will basically be some constant + the number of variables in scope. In a programming language like C, the size that this stack can take up is pretty much constant and allocated by the OS, in Java you can specify this size via JVM parameters but more or less this means that there's a finite number of functions within functions that one can call (this is one of the reasons why there's so much research being done to convert recursive algorithms to iterative ones).

Now what this means for your case is that the extra memory required for the function call is just a pointer to where the calling function was when the call occurred, which is basically a very low price to pay.

Overall what you are doing is pretty common and I have no indication to believe that it's bad practice (although routing is probably better practice for your specific case).

Also, if you're using a PHP framework, then the extra cost of a single function call is very small compared to everything else that the framework is doing.